# Why does this code return a zero?

Tags: python, class

The following is some simple Python 2.6 code that I wrote. The code works as expected, except I am curious why a zero (0) is returned in the output?

Thank you very much!

```
class One(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 0

    def Two(self, *args):
        for x in args:
            if x == 1:
                print x
        return self

    def answer(self):
        print (self.A)

ABC = One()
ABC.Two(1, 1, 9, 0, 7).answer()
```

***OUTPUT***

```
1
1
0
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `self.A` is 0, is it not? `answer()` is printing `self.A`

Comment: Because `answer()` says to print `self.A`, which is initialized to 0 in `__init__` and never changed.

Comment: Are you asking about the exit code 0 message?

Comment: Hello Barmar - not the exit code, I should have been more clear.  I was asking about the '1, 1, 0' output.      Also to everyone else....Why all the down votes?  I am a coding beginner and this is my first question posted on stack overflow.  I was under the impression this was a site for posting questions and answers at all levels.

Comment: @LemonTiger Don't let them bother you, your question is quite alright, at least it's [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I've seen worst questions than yours in this site by far  :P

Comment: What do you expect yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you write it differently you'll understand what's going on:

```
class One(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 0

    def Two(self, *args):
        for x in args:
            if x == 1:
                print x
        return self

    def answer(self):
        print(self.A)

ABC = One()
ABC.Two(1, 1, 9, 0, 7)
print '-' * 80
ABC.answer()
```

As you can see, the method `answer`is the one returning zero, not the method `Two`

Comment: Thank you, I rewrote it and it makes sense now.

Comment: @LemonTiger You're welcome, best way to thanks somebody here in stackoverflow is validating the answer it helped you the most. Also, don't be bothered by downvotes... In any case, maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you next time you ask again. Welcome to SO